# Multiplying Product Via Loop in R

Tags: r, math, product, multiplication

I want to multiply all the element in the `fact` vector,
namely:

```
final_prod = 0.01 * 0.05 * 0.02
```

This is how I do it in loop.

```
fact <- c(0.01,0.05,0.02)

final_prod <- 1;
for (i in 1:range(fact)){
   all_prod <- all_prod * fact[i];
}

print(final_prod)
```

But the final product it gave is wrong. It should be 
0.00001 instead of 0.01.

What's wrong with my approach above?

I understand there is R'ish way. But the reason
I want to do it in loop is because there is more complex
computation involved.

Comment: Check the function `range`. It doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: that doesn't even do what you claim... you need to put in the exact code.  Perhaps you mean to initialize all_prod instead of final_prod (and return all_prod as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Rather than `range`, you want `1:length(fact)`.
2. You are switching between the variables `final_prod` and `all_prod`, such that `all_prod` is never defined at the start.
3. Why don't you want to do this the R way, which takes less code? However complicated the computation involved is, it's probably possible (you could try explaining it here), but for this you would just use the function `prod`:

   ```
   final_prod = prod(fact)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The `range` function returns a two element vector and the ":" dyadic operator is only taking the first one. So you are getting 1:0.01 which is just 1 and then a single term product fact[1]. You could have used,

```
for (i in fact) {all_prod <- all_prod * i }
```

...although David Robinson has already shown you how to use `prod` more economically: